# Quartz drawing how to smudge

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, quartz-graphics

I have an iOS drawing app. It uses quartz and has a current stroke and then saves it to an image which is the background. I was wondering how I would add a smudge tool, I already have erasing.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: I know it is an old question, but for anyone interested. I wrote a simple Core Graphics aka Quartz 2D implementation in Swift here: https://github.com/joqqy/Basic-Smudge-Brush-in-Core-Graphics

Answer (score 0):

Did you search?  I found this implementation pretty quickly: 
<strike>http://losingfight.com/blog/2007/09/04/how-to-implement-smudge-and-stamp-tools/</strike>

(above link died - but available at the wayback machine)
http://web.archive.org/web/20120130144252/http://losingfight.com/blog/2007/09/04/how-to-implement-smudge-and-stamp-tools

Answer (score 0):

I think smudge is usually implemented as a convolution on the bits of your image. You will need to write custom code to get at and process the raw data of the image - there's no particular CoreGraphics call for it.